# Luggage transfer for cycling holidays around Dresden

Tags: luggage, germany, bicycles

We would like to cycle along Elbe river and sleep on campings and are looking for a company that would organise luggage transfer between the sites. What is the best way to get this organised?

Comment: The magic google words to unlock your answer are "wandern ohne gepäck dresden". Use those and you'll get lots of people ready to organise your luggage movements. Don't forget the umlaut.

Comment: It's a WANTA closure vote from me however. Sorry.